# Forms Based Authentication - default page

Tags: development

I have mixed authentication on my site ("Windows" and FBA). 
If I go to site url I should be redirected to default.apx from 14hive\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN folder which contain LogonSelector control which give me possibility to choose win or fba login.

question is: If I choose from above selector "FBA" I SHOULD be redirected to default.aspx from
14hive\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\FORMS AND if I look at site url (in IE) it seems that I'm really redirected on that page but If I modify that page I can't see any modification which I made which indicate that SP get that page from some other location.

Totally weird. Please any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found location. It seems that SP copy default.aspx from
14hive\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\FORMS
to X:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\XXXXX_forms (it would be nice that we know when he copies that, in the process of installation or later ?!?)
but in the case of first "default.aspx" it reads it from 14hive\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN.

Good to know.